# Android ListView Weird Behaviour

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get calls and sms log in a listview form a service via broadcast.
The problem is when the app runs, an empty listview appears with horizontal lines of each element on it. And when you click any of the element then data in it flashes and when you release the click, listview becomes blank again.

Please help where am I going wrong ?

LogServiceActivity.java

```
package com.logservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class LogServiceActivity extends ListActivity {

    public MyResultReceiver mReceiver;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_service);

        //start the service
        mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ServiceClass.MY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);

        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceClass.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_log_service, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

        super.onStop();
    }

    public class MyResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        ArrayList<String> callList = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String log = intent.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED");
            callList.add(log);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, callList));
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceClass.java:

```
package com.logservice;

import java.text.DateFormat;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceClass extends Service {
      Intent intent = new Intent();

    private static final String TAG = null;
    final static String MY_ACTION = "My ACTION";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

        int numberColumnId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int durationId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int contactNameId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        int dateId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int numTypeId = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);

        // ArrayList<String> callList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String result;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
                String contactName = cursor.getString(contactNameId);
                String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
                String callDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateId);

                result ="Contact Number: " + contactNumber
                        + "\nContact Name: " + contactName + "\nDuration: "
                        + duration + "\nDate: " + callDate;

                intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                intent.putExtra("DATAPASSED",result);

                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");   
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LogServiceActivity" >

  <ListView 
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: Have You tried this setCacheColorHint(0)? Also, do Your text in items has color different from background?

Comment: Yes, I have tried setCacheColorHint(0) but same problem. Listview has white background. whenyou click any element that area becomes orange and data in black color appears.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set text colors. Make sure your textview colors are not white. I see you are using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 for list view items. If you set the application theme holo dark than it's text color may be defaulted to white and they may not be visible on your white background.

Comment: i did not select holo dark theme, i selected None. Now i havent placed any textviews so where should i change text colors ?